# What is the findViewHolderForAdapterPosition inside an adapter Equivelant?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a custom adapter with 16 different view holder types. I would like to obtain the view holder at a specific position when a method is called.

Now I can do this outside of the adapter with

```
recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0)
```

Is it possible to create this effect inside the adapter?

Also to clarify, I do not mean anything involving "onBindViewHolder" as I wish to iterate through my list of items and obtain details from the various textfields and radio buttons inside my adapter.

Additional edit regarding my design:
The reason for this feature is the last view holder is a "submit" button. When clicked, it calls a method to iterate through the various adapter's textfields and radio buttons to build a custom object. Then making a callback to the activity. Here the object with the iterated data is uploaded to the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what's your design but `ViewHolder`s should only present the data and not hold any valuable information that would be worth iterating over. Regardless:

`RecyclerView.Adapter` can be used by multiple `RecyclerView`s simultaneously so there's no 1:1 relationship.

If you're using it only for one you can just keep hard reference to your `recyclerView` and call `findViewHolderForAdapterPosition` on it:

```
// inside Adapter
private var currentRecyclerView : RecyclerView? = null

override fun onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView : RecyclerView) {
    currentRecyclerView = recyclerView
}

override fun onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView : RecyclerView){
    currentRecyclerView = null
}
```

Then you can use `currentRecyclerView?.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(Int)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pawel, I added an explanation to my question explaining my overall design and why I need this function. I didn't want to over complicate this question by posting a big long custom adapter code. Your solution would certainly work. Check out my edit, and let me know if you still think your answer is the best. Otherwise perhaps I should just accept that calling findViewHolderForAdapterPosition inside an activity is a better/preferred design.

Comment: @C.Skjerdal have you actually tested your solution? Especially on small screens where all viewholders won't fit at once. Once you start scrolling and views start being recycled "data" inside them will be lost. Ideally whenever you input text or check radio button you should immediately modify data object representing those fields. Then you can simply take data from that object when you submit and also refer to it during `onBindViewHolder` to restore any data that was input before.

Comment: Everything seems to continue to display just fine, I might have to test out a very long example to ensure this doesn't become an issue on more complicated situations. That does make me wonder if I can knock out two birds with one stone by "building my form" as the user selects items and fills in fields. I'll mark this as correct as this has been helpful and then some more. Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing it works only because having each item being it's own item view type violates `RecyclerView` pattern and prevents views from recycling, that's why data does not disappear when scrolling - it's just leaked from previous binding. About testing I meant submit iteration, because you should not be able to find any `ViewHolder` that is not currently attached to the `recyclerView` (outside view bounds).

Comment: Hmm, well I do repeat the each unique view (radio buttons) several times depending on the requirements. I will confirm tomorrow if my iteration works since this effects a design plan on two separate projects.

Comment: Yeah it crashed right away, thanks for the heads up!